# Does Salesforce support using a salt while hashing a value?

Tags: hash, salesforce, apex, sha256

I know I can do a regular SHA-256 hash in Salesforce with the following code:

```
Blob digest = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(valueToHash));
```

But am I correct that Salesforce doesn't support any salts with hashing?  Any workarounds suggested?